# how can i create and show auto calculated fields?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Hi im trying to make a field in my view which is **dicount (amount)** to be auto calculated by doing the following:

```
discount_amount=(sale_price * discount_percentage)/100
```

create_presupuestos_productos_table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('presupuestos_productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('presupuesto_id');
        $table->foreign('presupuesto_id')->references('id')->on('presupuestos');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->decimal('sale_price');
        $table->text('sale_coin');
        $table->integer('discount_percentage');
        $table->decimal('discount');
        $table->decimal('AlicuotaIVA');
        $table->text('commentary');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is the logic of my controller but i dont know if it is like this how i should implement logic in it.

**PresupuestoProductoController:**

```
public function store(Request $request){
/*dd($request->all());*/
$presupuestoProducto = new PresupuestoProducto();

$presupuestoProducto->presupuesto_id = $request->presupuesto_id;

$presupuestoProducto->sale_price = $request->sale_price;

$presupuestoProducto->discount_percentage = $request->discount_percentage;
$presupuestoProducto->discount = ($sale_price * $discount_percentage)/100;

$presupuestoProducto->save();
Session::flash('success');
return redirect()->route('presupuestos-productos.view');
 }
```

And this is my view:

```
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="sale_price">Precio de Venta</label>
                        <input type="number"  pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="00.01" name="sale_price" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="discount_percentage">Porcentaje de descuento (%)</label>
                        <input type="number" name="discount_percentage" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="discount">Descuento</label>
                        <input type="number" name="discount" class="form-control">
                    </div>
```

How can i make so that the last field instead of being an input, to show the result of the auto calculated result in my controller?

Comment: Where it come from `$sale_price` in your controller?

Comment: sale_price is a column of my database table it is in my migration, and i get it through the form. @A.ANoman

Comment: You have already done this in your controller. You don't need last input field

Comment: You need the product object in your view to access his value.
Pass into de return statement and call him in the value of the input with you desire

Comment: so in the view in the last input i should do value="discount" or                             value="{{$presupuestoProducto->discount}}" @A.ANoman